# MATLAB object oriented with .Net object orinted

Tags: .net, matlab

How to access MATLAB class (classdef) in .Net ? I need to get static methods in MATLAB to .net enviroment? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to following pages. In short, I believe you can access Matlab class in .net with commercial package like NetBuilder. Otherwise, you might be able to access methods in Matlab via COM or native C API.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/matlabeng.aspx

http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/